# Bulma same width and same height columns

Tags: css, flexbox, height, bulma

I need to create two columns with the same height and the same width with Bulma css.
So I used column is-6 to achieve same width and tried to use is-flex to achieve the same height. But as I add the is-flex the height is same BUT the is-6 rule is ignored. So I tried to add simple width 100% to the wrapper div. Then I lost the same height added by is-flex.

Here is the [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/7uo3axyq/3/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <title>jQquery sortable lists example</title>
  <!-- Bulma css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
<style>
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  xoverflow: hidden;
  padding: 0!important;
}

body {
    background-color: #e9ecef;
}

.view-wrapper {
}

.nav {
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background-color: #42b983;
}

#visualCards .column {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.visualCard {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>    
<div class="nav"></div>
  <div class="container">
        <div id="visualCards" class="columns">
            <div class="column is-6">
                    <div class="columns visualCard">
                        <div class="column is-3">
              aaaa aaa aaaa aaa aaa aaa aaaa aaaa
            </div>
                        <div class="column is-8">
              bbbbb bbb bbbb bbbb bbb bbb bbb bbb
            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-6">
                    <div class="columns visualCard">
                        <div class="column is-3 is-flex">
              aaaa aa aaaaaa
            </div>
                        <div class="column is-8 is-flex">
              bbbb bb bbbbb bb
            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

If you remove the .visualCard width:100% you will get the same height.
I am lost in it. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Using tiles is an option:

```
<div class="tile is-ancestor">
  <div class="tile is-horizontal">
    <div class="tile is-parent">
      <div class="tile is-child box">
        Hello...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile is-parent">
      <div class="tile is-child box">
        Is it me you're looking for?<br>
        Is it me you're looking for?<br>
        Is it me you're looking for?<br>
        Is it me you're looking for?<br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```